# Why does a TypeScript generic suppress type errors?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Take the following TypeScript example.

```js
function expectInterface(args: { foo: string }): void {}

function passthrough<T>(fields: T): T {
  return fields
}

expectInterface({
  foo: 'bar',
  badKey: 'baz', // error
})

expectInterface(passthrough({
  foo: 'bar',
  badKey: 'baz', // no error
}))
```

Why does `passthrough` cause the type error on `badKey` to get suppressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error on `badKey` is suppressed because TypeScript uses a **structural typing** system.   This means that *one type X is compatible with another type Y if type X contains at least all the fields which type Y has*. See the [type compatibility section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) in the TypeScript docs for more specific details.

For clarity, let's name your interfaces `HasFoo` and `HasFooAndBadKey`.

```js
interface HasFoo {
  foo: string;
}

interface HasFooAndBadKey {
  foo: string;
  badKey: string;
}
```

You can see that `HasFooAndBadKey` contains the field `foo`, which means it is compatible with type `HasFoo`. Therefore this code is valid and compiles just fine:

```js
const withBadKey: HasFooAndBadKey = {
  foo: "bar",
  badKey: "baz"
};

const item: HasFoo = withBadKey;
```

However, assigning the same way using a literal will fail with the error `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'badKey' does not exist in type 'HasFoo'.`

```js
const other: HasFoo = {
  foo: "bar",
  badKey: "baz" // Error
}
```

Therefore your error isn't caused by generics. Your error is happening because you are only allowed to specify known properties in literals. Your generic passthrough function does not result in a compile time error because in this case it is returning a non-literal value which is type compatible with `HasFoo`. Explicitly typing passthrough to take a `HasFoo` and passing it the same literal containing `badKey` will result in the same error.

```js
interface HasFoo {
  foo: string;
}
interface HasFooAndBadKey {
  foo: string;
  badKey: string;
}

function expectInterface(args: HasFoo): void {}

function passthrough<T>(fields: T): T {
  return fields
}

// Expecting literal HasFoo, which can only have a foo field
expectInterface({
  foo: 'bar',
  badKey: 'baz', // error
})

const item: HasFooAndBadKey = {
  foo: 'bar',
  badKey: 'baz'
};

expectInterface(item); // No error

// Non-literal value returned by passthrough. The non-literal
// is type compatible with HasFoo, so no error occurs.
expectInterface(passthrough<HasFooAndBadKey>({
  foo: 'bar',
  badKey: 'baz', // no error
}))

// Now passthrough shows an error becuase we told it to expect a HasFoo,
// and this HasFoo literal cannot contain any other key than 'foo'.
expectInterface(passthrough<HasFoo>({
  foo: 'bar',
  badKey: 'baz', // error
}))
```

Comment: That makes sense, if perhaps a little awkward. Is there a way to specify _no additional fields_? Eg. `{ foo: string, [key: any]: never }` or some such?

Comment: Sadly, I don't think there is a way to do this directly. I have tried using `[key: string]: never` and that does not work. However, you might be able to achieve something similar using  [discriminating unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) or [instanceof type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards).